# Launchpad PPA supporting multiple versions of Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, application-development, ppa, packaging, launchpad

Is it possible for a Launchpad PPA to support multiple Ubuntu versions such as 10.04 and 12.04 when the package itself was built on a 12.04 machine? When trying to add the PPA to a older machine, it gives an error saying it was made on a 12.04 system and that it could not install.

I'd like `sudo get-apt-install my-app` to work with both 10.04 and 12.04, and I am new to packaging and PPA's so I do not know if anything like this exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as long as:

- The package builds in all targeted series
- The series is a supported Ubuntu version in Launchpad

Check out the [help on PPAs](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA#Supported_series) for more info:

> When building a source package you can specify one of the supported series in your [changelog](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/debian-dir-overview.html#the-changelog) file which are listed at the [Launchpad PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) page.

Comment: So... does that mean I need one github branch per distribution I want to support on Launchpad? Because from what I can see, I have to change the name of the distribution in my `debian/changelog` file... (`<package> (<version>) <distribution>; urgency=<urgency>`) and I really only can have one at a time in my master source directory.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** it is possible ,

A PPA is a place where you can build and publish your own packages. These can be custom versions of Ubuntu packages, or completely new packages, and can be built for [**any supported version of Ubuntu.**](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA).

When Launchpad builds a source package in a PPA, it creates binaries for: **x86 , AMD64**

From [PPA Launchpad Page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) ,**Personal Package Archives** (PPA) allow you to upload Ubuntu source packages to be built and published as an apt repository by Launchpad.

[image]